# Quoting issues in bash/linux

Tags: mysql, bash, quotes

I have a bash script that I'm putting some SQL select statements into but I'm having a horrible time getting them to read out properly. Single quotes, double quotes etc there doesn't seem to be a quick if you want the entire sql statement as is use this.

Sample:

```
declare -a array=(
'1=Unprocessed===SELECT count(*) FROM db.table WHERE thing1='unknown' and thing2='unknown' and thing3='unknown''
)
```

I've tired escaping the single quotes - I've tired double quotes around the whole thing. I've tried single and double quotes together etc

Comment: Nice to know...should I assume you were asking for something? :D
Please c.f. [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), then show us what you tried, your inputs, outputs, errors and code (not as images, please), and don't post it as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Someone will be able to help you make it work. ;)

Comment: You should show a small example script exhibiting the problem.

Comment: What the heck is `1=Unprocessed===`? For the quotes, try: `"SELECT count(*) FROM db.table WHERE thing1='unknown' and thing2='unknown' and thing3='unknown' "`

Answer (score 1):

idk what `1=Unprocessed===` is supposed to be but this seems to be what you're asking for:

```
$ declare -a array=(
'1=Unprocessed===SELECT count(*) FROM db.table WHERE thing1='\''unknown'\'' and thing2='\''unknown'\'' and thing3='\''unknown'\'''
)

$ echo "${array[0]}"
1=Unprocessed===SELECT count(*) FROM db.table WHERE thing1='unknown' and thing2='unknown' and thing3='unknown'
```